# Is there a IC to decode Johnson code to BCD 8421 or 7-segment?

Tags: digital-logic, decoder

I'm studying Johnson counter and want to display the counting on a 7-segment display. Is there an IC to decode Johnson code to BCD 8421 or directly to a 7-segment displays?

Comment: This is really on a knife's edge between asking for whether someone in the history of logic circuits has made something (maybe) interesting, and asking for a product recommendation. Note that product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic here. Note that I'm also assuming this is not a product recommendation question, as I can't think of a non-obsolete use case for the IC you're describing.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask for a product. We have a bunch of ICs, of different kinds of families, like TTL and CMOS. I was looking for a IC that could decode a Johnson code to BCD 8421, like an IC 4511 is used to decode BCD to 7-segment.

Comment: Really tough here, right? Sorry to bother, maybe this question should be deleted. There is a lot of manufacturers that could assembly an IC like this, I'm not asking for it. I just want to know if there is a member of TTL or CMOS family taht could help me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It's far from really tough here. But you must be confusing it with a not a general-purpose electronics discussion forum, which it's not. So it's no tougher than getting an 'off-topic' reply from a woodworking forum. Please do take the tour if you're unclear about the site's goals. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look for "10-line to 4-line priority encoders".

The 74147 is one such type.

[image]

*From the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls148.pdf?ts=1605338111713&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).*

> These TTL encoders feature priority decoding of the inputs to ensure that only the highest-order data line is
> encoded. The ’147 and ’LS147 devices encode nine data lines to four-line (8-4-2-1) BCD. The implied decimal
> zero condition requires no input condition, as zero is encoded when all nine data lines are at a high logic level.
> The ’148 and ’LS148 devices encode eight data lines to three-line (4-2-1) binary (octal). Cascading circuitry
> (enable input EI and enable output EO) has been provided to allow octal expansion without the need for external
> circuitry. For all types, data inputs and outputs are active at the low logic level. All inputs are buffered to represent
> one normalized Series 54/74 or 54/74LS load, respectively

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!